# VueJS Router redirect to server path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using the following router settings:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  linkActiveClass: 'open active',
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      ....
```

with the following logout function declared in a .vue file:

```
logout () {
  this.$router.push('/logout')
}
```

When I run the app the path is:

```
www.mydomain.com/app#/router_paths
```

so when I run the logout function above I am redirected to:

```
www.mydomain.com/app#/logout
```

I tried using:

```
<b-dropdown-item ><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> <a href="logout">Logout</a> </b-dropdown-item>
```

which while hard coded will work for local and server, I hover over the link and it shows

```
www.mydomain.com/logout
```

But when I click it nothing happens - ie I am not redirected

How can I tell router to redirect to

```
www.mydomain.com/logout
```

(without just hard coding this in the code - as I want to run on local as well as deployed instances)

Comment: So you want to redirect outside of the webapp? or just clean the url?

Comment: redirect outside of webapp

Comment: yes but then it wouldnt work for localhost:5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.replace('/logout')
```

> The replace() method replaces the current document with a new one.

from w3.

```
logout () {
  window.location.replace('/logout');
}
```

then use

```
<button v-on:click="logout">Logout</button>
```